# Plotting a dataFrame with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

[image]

I have this data set here and I want to plot a graph showing population differences as-

```
x-axis : 'Name'
y-axis: ['TOT_P','TOT_M','TOT_F']
```

Here's what I tried ,

```
df_State.plot(x='Name',y=['TOT_P','TOT_M','TOT_F'],linewidth=2)
```

[image]

But all the name in `'Name'` are not present in the `x-axis` if you notice clearly and these are all clustered together .

I'm not sure whether this is happening due to clustering of large number of names in small region . Or is it due to duplicates existing in `'Name'` column
Now , these are segregated as `Total,Urban,Rural` in `TRU` column So am i supposed to take `TRU` column also into consideration wile plotting the garph ?If so , how ?

Comment: is a line plot the way to go for this ? why not use a bar plot if you are showing differences via state? also interesting to see the disparity with urban & rural population in Kashmir.

Comment: what is ur expected output

Comment: @Manakin How can I do with bar plot ? An answer would be a great help .Thanks for suggestion of urban & rural population Kashmir